# Submit button not responding when dropdown is present

Tags: html

I have the following HTML `form` in my HTML page. The problem is that the submit button is not responding (I cannot click on it.) I discovered that this problem happens only if the dropdown is present inside the form. If I comment out the dropdown (`#jobtype`) it works fine. Can any one please tell what is wrong here?

```
   <form action="register.php" name="form1" method="post" onSubmit="validate()" >
                                 <select id="jobtype">
                                   <option value="" disabled selected>--Select-- </option>
                                     <option value="11" >All</option>
                                <option value="1" >Contract</option>
                                <option value="2" >Full Time</option>
                                <option value="3" >PartTime </option>
                                 <option value="0" >Other</option>
                                 </select> 
                                 <input type="text" id="others" placeholder="Please specify"/>
                                    <input type="text" name="email"  placeholder="e-mail address">
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" title="GO" value="GO"  >

                                </form>
```

Comment: what is validate method here

Comment: Post your validate() function code

Comment: It has something to do with other code inside your HTML, outside your form code (floats, absolute/fixed positioning, framework modifications). In JSFiddle the plain form you posted works fine; http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/gcbMb/

Comment: edited question to add javascript

Comment: Can you also add CSS for the snippet as well? May be a case of positioning which is not allowing it to work. - @logeeks

Comment: please check your firebug console for any javascript errors

Comment: @BogdanEmilMariesan Thanks, this error is happening on google chrome.

Comment: I tried and it works fine. It could be indentation issue @logeeks. Remove spaces..

Comment: @logeeks and does the developer console show any errors? press F12 and check that

Answer (score -1):

I have verified your code in IE8 and it works fine for me...
the submit button functions though the drop down exists...
please check once again...